# Not able to access Generic List C# MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a certain requirement wherein I need to assign string values from array to my generic model attribute list, but not able to access the model structure and getting the following error:

> NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code.
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My model structure is as follows:

```
namespace ExamEvent.Models
{
    public class Author
    {
        public string AuthId { get; set; }
        public string AuthName { get; set; }
        public List<Books> AuthBooks { get; set; }
    }

    public class Books
    {
        public string BookId { get; set; }
        public string BookName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Note: I've created List of Books.

In my controller I've tried the following (including the commented line):
 I'm getting above error in foreach.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Author author = new Author();
    string[] bookId = {"30", "43", "44", "56", "45"};
    foreach (var item in bookId)
    {
        author.AuthBooks[0].BookId = item;
        //author.AuthBooks[author.AuthBooks.IndexOf(item)].BookId
    }
    return View(author);
}
```

Comment: You need to instantiate `AuthBooks`. And this question is asked extremely regularly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Because `AuthBooks` is `null` - you need to initialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    author.AuthBooks = new List<Book>();
    foreach (var item in bookId)
    {
        author.AuthBooks.Add(new Book {bookId = item, BookName = "bookName"});
    }
```